# CoreText flip coordinates self.bounds.size.height error bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-text, bounds

I am drawing text in the view with CoreText. To learn this I used a tutorial, but suddenly it uses `self.bounds.size.height`, in a part where it flips the coordinate system. When I was duplicating the code in Xcode it gave an error because 'bounds' was not a structure or union. Why is this a error and can anyone give a small but detailed explanation of why it uses `bounds`
Thanks on forehand,
Nicholas

Comment: Where do you call this `self.bounds.size.height` code from?

Comment: I got the code from this tutorial: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/befriending-core-text/

Comment: No, I mean where did you put that code? If it's inside UIView subclass, it should be ok, but I'm guessing it's inside UIViewController subclass. In that case it should be `self.view.bounds.size.height`

Comment: Yes I did, but now you've mentioned, it makes a lot more sense putting it in a subclass of UIView, thanks!

Comment: Ok, I posted my comment as an answer, so please accept it if it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you placed that code inside a UIViewController subclass, it should be: `self.view.bounds.size.height`. Or put it in a UIView subclass like in the tutorial you followed.